# Best way to express "less than an hour in the future" in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

If a train leaves less than an hour from now, I want its row in the schedule table to be highlighted red. Currently I'm doing the calculation like this:

```
if Time.zone.now + 1.hour > t[from_station]
  # do whatever
end
```

This works and kind of makes sense, but I wonder if there's a clearer / more idiomatic way to express this (I could imagine coming back to this code in a few months and having to pause for a moment to mentally parse `Time.zone.now + 1.hour`).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use [`from_now`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Numeric/Time.html#M001243):

```
if t[from_station] <  1.hour.from_now
```

When using `Time.zone.now`, you'll have to specify it, so [`since`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Numeric/Time.html#M001242) is probably more readable (`from_now` is just an alias to `since`):

```
if t[from_station] < 1.hour.since(Time.zone.now)
```

Comment: Great answer. Is there any way to make `1.hour.from_now` (which seems like the most correct way to express this) work with the Rails app's default timezone (as defined in environment.rb)?

Comment: `from_now` takes a single argument.  By default it uses `Time.now`.  You can, of course, pass it `Time.zone.now` just as I did with `since` (they're actually the same method).  If you want `Time.now` set to the correct timezone (so that you don't even have to provide an argument), you have to set `ENV['TZ']` (or the `TZ` environment variable) to the correct timezone, too.